# EntityManager returning always null

Tags: java, tomcat, cdi

Every time that i request the entityManager it is null, see:

```
@Named
@ApplicationScoped
@AnBasicDAO
public class BasicDAOImpl implements BasicDAO, Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="generalPU")
    protected EntityManager entityManager;
```

This is my persistence.xml:

```
<persistence-unit name="generalPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>     
        <non-jta-data-source>java:/comp/env/jdbc/testeDS</non-jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache"
                value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="50" />            
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

This is my resource in server.xml (tomcat):

```
<Context docBase="/home/usertest/Programas/apache-tomcat-7.0.59/webapps/cardoso" path="/cardoso" reloadable="false" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:cardoso">
 <Resource name="jdbc/testeDS" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          username="postgres"
          password="pgadmin"
          driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
          url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/teste"
          maxTotal="25"
          maxIdle="10"
          validationQuery="select 1" />

</Context>
```

My context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
  <ResourceLink global="jdbc/sabrecadoDS" name="jdbc/testeDS" type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
   <Manager pathname=""/> <!-- disables storage of sessions across restarts -->
   <Resource name="BeanManager"
      auth="Container"
      type="javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager"
      factory="org.jboss.weld.resources.ManagerObjectFactory"/>
</Context>
```

Something is wrong ? THe EntityManager is always null. A some time ago i used Spring (now CDI) and in applicationContext i defined the  and worked normally.

Comment: How are you getting a reference to your `BasicDAOImpl`?

Comment: Sorry i didnt undersant your question.

Comment: CDI does not work out of the box in tomcat. You need a JavaEE application server, such as TomEE or Glassfish. With tomcat, you need to use a standalone CDI container, such as Weld.

Comment: I'm using Weld as CDI implematation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CDI doesn't understand `@PersistenceContext`. So change it to:

```
@Inject
protected EntityManager entityManager;
```

But then you would have to define the `EntityManager` somewhere, lets say:

```
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Disposes;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

import org.apache.deltaspike.jpa.api.transaction.TransactionScoped;

public class CdiApplicationConfig {

    @Inject
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;

    @Produces
    @ApplicationScoped
    public EntityManagerFactory createEntityManagerFactory() {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("generalPU");
        return emf;
    }

    public void close(@Disposes EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        emf.close();
    }

    @Produces
    @TransactionScoped // is a bit better than @RequestScoped because it won't allow perform injection outside transaction context
    public EntityManager createEntityManager() {
        return emf.createEntityManager();
    }

    public void close(@Disposes EntityManager em) {
        if (em.isOpen()) {
            em.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Above code uses `DeltaSpike` for transaction management - but you can use whatever you want instead.

One more tip: I'm not sure if slash is allowed between `java:/comp` in the datasource name referenced inside `persistence.xml`, so please check also:

```
  <non-jta-data-source>java:comp/env/jdbc/testeDS</non-jta-data-source>
```

As you can see, CDI is very similar to Spring.

Comment: how CDI know that createEntityManagerFactory() should be called in injection of ENtityManager attribute ?

Comment: In an EE-Server you can still use @PersistenceContext as well as with the resource-module from (and for) OpenWebBeans.

Comment: Why this just work in EE-Server ? And What the EE-Server more used ?

Comment: @DarWhi true, but this post is clearly about Tomcat + Weld, so we are outside the resource-hungry Java EE servers.

Comment: @Scientist `@PersistenceContext` would work in Java EE servers, because they must honor this annotation. CDI is simpler. It only knows how to inject beans which have been declared previously with `@Produces`. In short: CDI looks at the returned type of such Producer method. To get the details, read [CDI doc](https://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html).

Comment: thanks your solution with CdiApplicationConfig class works;

Comment: @G.Demecki yes - but you could use TomEE. It's Tomcat + all libs from Apache (preconfigured) to get a light EE server. It uses way less resources than other servers and you don't have to do the hard work on your own (it's really not needed any longer (as it used to be with EE5). Instead of wasting your time with the setup, just start with your application.

Comment: @DarWhi as I said, true :-) Don't get me wrong, TomEE is still a "Java EE server". And it still has EJB/ JSF/ JSP/ Javamail etc - which you do not necessarily need. Also you got a **broken deployment model** - where server rules your application. Java EE is a lost platform from my point of view. And the price of moving away from "Java EE" buzz is relatively low - the matter of setup. Is it worth? Answer is as always: **it depends on the use case**.

Comment: I don't agree, because Tomcat + Weld is the same when it comes to a deployment. You deploy your application as a Web-Archive as you do with TomEE. At runtime the main overhead are some classes in the permgen space which aren't a big deal. The startup is almost the same and the larger your app, the faster it will be compared to Tomcat + Weld, because classpath-scanning just happens once with TomEE and not twice as with Tomcat + Weld. In the end Tomcat is the implementation of the Servlet spec. and Weld of the CDI spec. - so you already have a tiny EE-Server (if you like it or not).

Comment: @DarWhi lets discuss it further in the [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92874/questions-33137869)

Comment: @G.Demecki comments added to the chat